# Removing contours from an image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have contours which i want to delete  from the image, What is the best way to do it ?

```
image = cv2.imread(path)
gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
retr , thresh = cv2.threshold(gray_image, 190, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
contours, hier = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
for c in contours:
    if cv2.contourArea(c) > 20:
        x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
         ##### how to continue from here  ?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an empty mask in the size of the image:
`mask = np.zeros(image.shape[:2], dtype=image.dtype)`

Next draw all the contours / boundingrect you want to keep on this mask:
`cv2.drawContours(mask, [cnt], 0, (255), -1)`
Alternatively you can instead draw the contours you **don't** want and inverse the mask (this may be more suitable in some situations):
`mask= cv2.bitwise_not(mask)`

Use the mask on the main image:
`result = cv2.bitwise_and(image,image, mask= mask)`

**Edit:** added code after comment.

I assumed this is about the image in your other question, so I applied the code to that image.

Result:

[image]

Code:

```
import numpy as np 
import cv2
# load image
image = cv2.imread('image.png')
# create grayscale
gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
# perform threshold
retr , thresh = cv2.threshold(gray_image, 190, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
# find contours
ret, contours, hier = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
# create emtpy mask
mask = np.zeros(image.shape[:2], dtype=image.dtype)

# draw all contours larger than 20 on the mask
for c in contours:
    if cv2.contourArea(c) > 20:
        x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
        cv2.drawContours(mask, [c], 0, (255), -1)

# apply the mask to the original image
result = cv2.bitwise_and(image,image, mask= mask)

#show image
cv2.imshow("Result", result)
cv2.imshow("Image", image)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: When i run this line: 

     result = cv2.bitwise_and(image,image, mask= mask)
i get this error OpenCV(4.0.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\core\src\arithm.cpp:245: error: (-215:Assertion failed) (mtype == CV_8U || mtype == CV_8S) && _mask.sameSize(*psrc1) in function 'cv::binary_op'

Comment: The datatypes need to be similar, which I forgot to set. It is correct in the above code

Comment: yeah, mask = np.zeros(thresh.shape[:2], dtype=np.uint8) fixed it , Thank you very much!